# How to move objects in OpenGL independently

Tags: opengl

Given I have several cubes drawn on the canvas, how can they be moved independently of each other? How to define distinct onmouseup/onmousedown/onmousemove listeners to each cube?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without any source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to define distinct onmouseup/onmousedown/onmousemove listeners to each cube?

You normally have only one pointer on the screen, except in multitouch environments, or where individual pointers can be requested for each input device.

So having only one set of mouse event handlers is kind of natual. If you want some distinction between the objects, you must get creative and come up with some way to associate event position with the to be changed object. For example clicking on it.

OpenGL is just a drawing API. It doesn't deal with objects, it doesn't know what a mouse is, or what input events are and it doesn't manage a scene, which also means it won't give you free candy in form of per-object-listeners. All of this must be implemented by you (or some 3rd party library).

Comment: Thank you, that is more than helpful.

Comment: Also, I'd like to express my disagreement on the downvote as the question was about the concept of object moving, not about a certain scenario. Datenwolf's answer gave a very clear picture about how this kind of issue is usually handled. Please upvote that answer (as I'm unable to do so at the moment).